# XMPPFramework - Delete a registered user account

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for my iOS chat application.

I need help here to delete a registered user account.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [the section Entity Cancels an Existing Registration of XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#usecases-cancel), you need to send the following stanza to the server:

```xml
<iq type='set' id='unreg1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <remove/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

The server should then send a 'not-authorized' stream error and terminate the connection.

Comment: hello @legoscia .i am 
Unable to delete my Openfire Account using the above stanza

Comment: @Hemant, you may want to post a new question, including all XML stanzas sent between the client and the server, and the code you're using to delete the account.

Comment: @legoscia, please answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862569/delete-registered-user-account-from-openfire-using-xmpp-ios

Comment: @ Legoscia I am bit concerned with statement, "The server should then send a 'not-authorized' stream error and terminate the connection. ". Why server has to disconnect the stream when we send remove command ? Is it necessary to behave in that way ?  I am raising this concerns only because in our application after deleting an account we are also allowing a user to do re registration. In this case we have to send connect command to server again.  Comments pls....