# XMPPFramework - "not-authorized" error upon deleting a registered user account

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I want to delete an Openfire user which is currently connected using XMPP.

I use the below code for deleting the user:

```
- (void)DeleteAccountFromOpenfire
{
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"'jabber:iq:register'"];
    [query addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"remove"]];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"set" elementID:@"unreg1"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
}
```

But I get a `not-authorized` error from the server. How could I avoid that?

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Comment: @legoscia,  this is the iq i am getting

<iq type="set" id="unreg1"><query xmlns="'jabber:iq:register'"><remove></remove></query></iq>

Comment: @Hemant, that's the iq you're _sending_. What do you get back, as a response from the server?

Comment: @legoscia <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="789-4859712" from="grovemultiauth.com" to="grovemultiauth.com/d4e6899"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"></ping></iq> 

Then i am getting not-authorized Error..

Comment: Right, `not-authorized` is probably the critical bit here.  I'm not familiar with Openfire myself, but someone more knowledgeable will probably point out how to configure the server to allow account deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the solution to remove the registered user from openfire account

```
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:register"];
[query addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"remove"]];

NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"unreg1"];
[iq addChild:query];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
```